An optimized alternative to an exhaustive search in terms of time
I have a list of 53 points with associated losses for each, then I generate a list of n-combinations for these. The idea is that, for example, I take 3-combinations of these (53C3) which are around 23,000 combinations and change these values in the original 53 and evaluate the loss for each. So I have now have a list of ~23,000 items each with an associated loss, and I simply want to find the combination with the highest loss.
So far, I have been able to do this using an exhaustive search. But since I am running inference through a neural network on each combination it takes around 25 minutes to iterate through each one to find the combination with the highest loss. The code for the exhaustive search is as follows:
    attack_combinations = combinations(X_train_filtered.columns, num_attacked_ap)

    attack_combinations_list = []
    
    for attack in attack_combinations:
        attack_combinations_list.append(attack)
        
    with open('noise-high.txt') as file:
        file_contents = file.read()
    
    const_noise = np.fromstring(file_contents, sep=' ')
    
    aps_loss = {}

    best_loss = 0
    best_combination = 0

    for attack_combination in tqdm(attack_combinations_list):
        # Apply attack to the dataset
        X_val_attacked = deepcopy(X_val_filtered)  
        for col_name in X_val_attacked.columns:
            if col_name in attack_combination:
                
                noise = const_noise 
                X_val_attacked[col_name] += noise

        # Evaluate the model on the attacked dataset
        loss, accuracy, mse = model.evaluate(X_val_attacked, y_val_filtered, verbose=0)

        aps_loss[tuple(attack_combination)] = mse

        
        if mse > best_loss:
            best_loss = mse
            best_combination = attack_combination

    print("Best combination:", best_combination)
    print(f"Highest DL MSE for {num_attacked_ap}-combinations:", best_loss)

However, I want to try even greater n-combinations in which case the number of combinations increases to millions, making the exhaustive search infeasible. Therefore, I'd like to know if there are more efficient ways to do this, maybe using random sampling methods or genetic algorithms or reinforcement learning? Any guidance towards that direction would be appreciated.

Please clarify your question. Each point has an associated loss, and each set of k points also has a loss, which is apparently expensive to evaluate. What is the relationship between the two kinds of loss, or if there is none, why do we care that each point has an associated loss? Also, do we know anything about sets with large overlap? E.g., say 2 k-sets differ by a single point, and we know the cost of one of them and of both points of difference, does that help with the cost of the other k-set?

Also, you might want to tag this with 'algorithm' -- possibly replacing 'python' since this isn't a python problem.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
